# Normal distribution function:determine probability of a given point in Java

Tags: java, statistics, normal-distribution

My statistics since high school is gone

An I am struggling to find out a way to determine the probability of a given point in a Normal distribution in java.

I see that Colt `cern.jet.stat` offers a `Probability` with some methods

- `normal(double a)`
- `normal(double mean, double variance, double x)`
- `normalInverse(double y0)`

and Apache `org.apache.commons.math3.distribution` offers a `NormalDistribution` class and  which include some methods:

- `cumulativeProbability(double x)`
- `cumulativeProbability(double x0, double x1)`
- `density(double x)`
- `inverseCumulativeProbability(double p)`
- `probability(double x0, double x1)`
- `probability(double x)`

Which one to use for my purpose?

---

EDIT EDIT EDIT

The problem is to exclude outliers from a data set using [Chauvenet's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chauvenet%27s_criterion#Calculation)

> To apply Chauvenet's criterion, first calculate the mean and standard deviation of the observed data. Based on how much the suspect datum differs from the mean, **use the normal distribution function (or a table thereof) to determine the probability that a given data point will be at the value of the suspect data point**. Multiply this probability by the number of data points taken. If the result is less than 0.5, the suspicious data point may be discarded, i.e., a reading may be rejected if the probability of obtaining the particular deviation from the mean is less than 1/(2n)

Comment: A probability of any *point* in normal distribution is 0.

Comment: Well, if the problem is to implement Chauvenet's criterion, you don't need to calculate any probability values at all, since the criterion is equivalent to a datum being more than a certain multiple of the standard deviation away from the mean. I.e. the crtiterion is equivalent to a rule of the form "if abs(x - mean)/sd < FOO then OK else NOT OK" where FOO is something like 2 or 3 (depending on how stringent you want the criterion). You might have to find FOO by looking up 1/(2n) in a cumulative normal table, but in any event you do it just once for all data (not once per datum).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the question cannot be answered as is because in a continous distribution like the normal distribution, the probability of an specific point is always zero. You need to ask yourself what it is exactly you want to know in terms of an interval.

For example, `cern.jet.stat.Probability.normal(double)` will answer the question "What is the probability of the value being less than my value?" (Less than or equal is equivalent in this context.)

`org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.NormalDistribution.cumulativeProbability(double)` will also give you that same information.

If `p` if the probability of the value being less than your value, the probability of the value being higher than your value is  `1 - p`.

**Answer to edit**

In your edit, the relevant sentence part is this

> Based on how much the suspect datum differs from the mean (...)

You are looking for the probability of the suspect point being (at least) that far from the mean.

Let `x` be your suspect point. First, normalize it to be able to work with the normalized normal distribution, like so

```
xn = (x - mean) / standard deviation
```

The probability you are looking for is

```
2 * CPD( -abs(xn) )
```

Where CPD (cumulative probability distribution) is found with `org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.NormalDistribution.cumulativeProbability(double)` or `cern.jet.stat.Probability.normal(double)`.

That expression gives the probability of the normalized value being under `-abs(xn)` or over `abs(xn)`, which is exactly the same as saying the probability of being at least that far from the mean. `CPD( -abs(xn) )` gives the probability of being under `-abs(xn)` (by definition) and we can multiply by two to add the probability of being over `abs(xn)` because the normal distribution is symmetric relative to the mean.

Comment: @LisaAnne Please see my completed answer for a response to your edit.

Answer (score 1):

A probability of any *point* in normal distribution is **0**. 
For that reason, there is certainly **no** `NormalDistribution.probability(double x)` method, you are mistaken about it.

As for the other methods that are kinda relevant to your question:

`cumulativeProbability(double x)` is the probability of the value being less than `x`.

`probability(double x0, double x1)` returns the probability of a value being between `x0` and `x1`. It is equivalent to `cumulativeProbability(x1) - cumulativeProbability(x0)`;

`cumulativeProbability(double,double)` is deprecated and is actually the same as `probability(double,double)` (but very badly named).

Comment: That page is written very badly ("probability that a given data point will be at the value" is zero). I think, what you need is either `cumulativeProbability(x)` when `x < mean` and `1 - cumulativeProbability(x)` when `x > mean`. This would be the probability of a value being as far from the mean as your data point or father.

Answer (score 0):

`NormalDistribution.density` seems the one most appropriate. But it wouldn't hurt if you could say more about the problem you are trying to solve.